# View NHibernate session objects

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I keep getting an error when i delete an object from a collection that it will be resaved because it exists in other collections. In the current session only the collection I am working on exists. There aren't any others. 
So I think NHibernate is telling me that even though the object will be deleted, it still exists in the session.

How can i view the objects that are in the current session or in which collection did NHibernate find that the object that I am trying to delete belongs?

Comment: You should post the full exception.  As well as the mapping specific to the collection you are trying to delete an object in.  Also the code where you are trying to remove/delete this object.

Comment: did you forget to remove the object from some collection? session.Delete is not enough

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found it:

```
var sessionContext = session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext;
foreach (var entity in sessionContext.EntitiesByKey.Values)
{

}
```

the context contains all the objects that are in the session.